# refresh page when image content changes but image name doesn't ,php

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, refresh

I have an upload picture form. When the user changes the picture I overwrite the picture he already has.The picture always bears the user's name.

I use CodeIgniter, the  settings are:

```
$config['overwrite']=TRUE;
$config['file_name']=$this->session->userdata('username');
```

After he uploads the picture I reload the whole page

```
$this->load->view('bilet/uploadform');
```

I have to refresh the page in order for the new pic to appear, why is this ?

Why doesn't it work the way I expect it to? (I am not using AJAX yet,I will soon)

Comment: Indeed because you're not using AJAX. PHP's server side, once it has supplied an image to html, you need to refresh the page for php to submit a new one to the user. What's the problem, btw?

Answer (score 1):

if you save the new uploaded image name as the old one this is a caching issue , thats why you have to refresh , you can add a random generated number to the image name or in the src attribute add a random number like this for example :

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/image.png?number=123123
```

or

```
 http://www.mywebsite.com/image.png?number=6546587
```

somthing like this will prevent called cached images .

hope this will help .

Answer (score 0):

yeah, its common, you have to refresh the page if you are not using some ajax magic.

To do the refresh in the CI way .

Load the [URL helper](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html) .

And then

```
redirect('/path/to/controller', 'refresh');
```

Comment: Your answer sparked another question.Does CI cache the page automatically ?If the picture has the same name but a different content php won't be able to tell that the page is different and it will send me the old version of the view.If I use redirect like you said Krish,even without the 'refresh' option it works.(I guess because you redirect to a controller and then load the view.)